# Is it possible to change the Logical ID of an RDS instance in a Cloud Formation script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We have multiple AWS stacks for our application (dev, test, prod, etc). These are all created with Cloud Formation templates. Some bright person before me decided to use a different template for the prod stack to the rest. I'd like to consolidate to only having one Cloud Formation template.

I've done a file comparison between the two templates and the only difference is the Logical ID of the RDS instance. So we have something like this:

```
   "MyDbInstanceDev": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
      "Properties": {
        "AllocatedStorage": "200",
        "CopyTagsToSnapshot" : true,
        "DBInstanceClass": "db.m3.medium",
```

Verses:

```
   "MyDbInstance": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
      "Properties": {
        "AllocatedStorage": "200",
        "CopyTagsToSnapshot" : true,
        "DBInstanceClass": "db.m3.medium",
```

If I change the logical ID from "MyDbInstanceDev" to "MyDbInstance" though, cloud formation thinks that I want to delete the existing RDS instance and create a new one in the stacks where the original template had a the old logical ID.

Is there some way I can change the logical ID and make all my stacks have the same template without losing the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot do that using CFT as CFT maintains the state of stack (you can't see it though). Even if you rename the DBInstance, you will face problems down the road if you try to delete the stack.

You can use DBInstanceIdentifier as parameter and every time you want to create the DB, you create a new stack deployment and not update stack. `Logical Id` of the CFT resource does not have much significance unless you are `auto naming` the resources.

To fix your existing deployments, do this:

- Take a snapshot of the database that was deployed using
  `MyDbInstanceDev`.
- Add a parameter named `RestoreFromDBSnapshotIdentifier` in
  `MyDbInstance` CFT.
- Add `DBSnapshotIdentifier` property to `MyDbInstance` and set it conditionally if `RestoreFromDBSnapshotIdentifier` is not blank.
- Deploy.

Comment: I doubled checked with a solutions architect. He said the same - you have to keep the name an option is to not expose those names and keep the stack itself small such that you don't need to depend on it so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you would need to delete it from the stack and then import it. Given you have a current resource definition it isn't really a difficult process.
I notice you do not have a `DeletionPolicy: Retain` on the DB, you must have that in there before you delete the resource from the stack.
As long as you have a `Retain` policy, you can safely remove the resource from the CF file and deploy, which will result in the resource being removed from the stack. Directions are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html#resource-import-existing-stack-cli
After deploying, you just re-add the resource to the CF file using a new logical id, create your import file (described in the link) create and execute a changeset, and you are pretty much done.

Comment: I'll leave this for someone else to test as I resolved this issue years ago, but it sound's plausible.