# Changing logical ID of AppSync resolver result in error upon deploy (CDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

When I change a resolver ID as follows:

From:
`new appsync.Resolver(scope, "SuperResolver",.....`

To:
`new appsync.Resolver(scope, "MegaResolver",.....`

i.e from `"SuperResolver"` to `"MegaResolver"` and then I run `cdk deploy`, I get the following error:

> Only one resolver is allowed per field. (Service: AWSAppSync; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request
> ID: fd68b0ff-38a5-4149-a797-138baf6a836c; Proxy: null

It appears that instead of replacing the ID of the existing resolver (or deleting the construct with the old ID and creating a new one with the new ID), AppSync tries to attach a new resolver to the GQL field.

But the error is rather bogus, so my assumption may be incorrect.

Did anyone experience such a problem?
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because CloudFormation firstly creates new resources before it deletes old ones. In this case you have to delete resolver in one deploy and add new one in the next.

Comment: You sure about that?
That will result in endpoint(for a the specific field operation to which the resolver is attached) downtime.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I know, but this is what it is, you cant change logical id without recreate the resource. And if you can only have one resource it will be a downtime. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269818/is-it-possible-to-change-the-logical-id-of-an-rds-instance-in-a-cloud-formation

Comment: in this case you have to change `fieldName` as well, if it is the same field just leave logical id as is

Comment: Thanks @Lasek. I've been thinking about how to employ  (least painfully) a feature toggling approach.
Developing different resolver for this field and switch/toggle between the two via configuration.